# Can I use PCA for rating scale?

Tags: pca

I want to conduct PCA on gambling behaviors and one of these behaviors is their participation. I would be asking them how likely they are to participate in different gambling activities, on a scale of 1 to 10. Can I use these questions as my variable for PCA?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello, I want to reduce the variables on gambling behaviors, specifically gambling behaviors in social mobile gaming I have questions about how likely they are to participate in different events and monetary mechanics (that are proven to somewhat enhance gambling behavior in social mobile gaming). I would like to know if I can use this rating scale questions for PCA.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. What are "they" in l.2? Please try to make grammatically correct possibly short sentences as this is hard to read. It is still not clear to me why variables (I guess you mean the number of variables) need to be reduced.

Comment: Hello, I forgot to mention, that "they" is referring to my respondents. I want to determine the gambling patterns of mobile social gamers (my respondents). Specifically, I will be using PCA to reduce the number of variables on gambling patterns to a smaller set of components.

Comment: Without knowing more details I can say that you *can* use PCA, but it may not be very good, and better alternatives may exist. I can't say anything more though as I don't understand your data and task enough.

Comment: Thanks, Christian!